# Show an alert if the value ("email") was not found in the input search

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that looks for an email and displays the data from an api call. I want to display an alert('Email not found') if the email does not exist in the data. How can I achieve this?

This is my code that I have

```js
async function search() {
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
  if (!email) return alert("error.");
  const url = `https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/i3dp73wvi19kf/search?EMAIL=${email}`;
  const token = "my-api-key";
  const method = "GET";
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Result not OK");
    const data = await res.json();

    // if api didnt respond use this instead data to generate result
    var jsondata = [{
      "CARGO": "JEFE",
      "CIUDAD": "CIUDAD1",
      "EMAIL": "jperez",
      "Función": "OPERACIONES",
      "NOMBRE": "JUAN PEREZ",
      "Unidad organizativa": "OPERACIONES"
    }]
    let text = ""
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = "Searching...";
    var keys = [];
    text += "<table border==\"1\"><tr>";
    for (key in data[0]) {
      text += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
    }
    text += "</tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      text += '<tr>';
      for (key in data[i]) {
        text += '<td>' + data[i][key] + '</td>';
      }
      text += '</tr>';
    }
    text += "</table>";

    output.innerHTML = text;
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="search(); event.preventDefault(); return false">
  <label>EMAIL: <input type=search id="email"></label>
  <button type=submit>Search</button>
</form>
<hr />
<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: Something like `if (data.length == 0) { alert("Email not found"); }`?

Comment: Where should I add that line of code?

Comment: Before the code that creates the table from `data`.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a flag variable at the beginning of your function and initialize it to false e.g.:

```
let emailFound = false
```

Then, inside the results loop you can compare each email with the initial one  and if a match is found, set the flag to true like:

```
if (data[i].email == email) {
  emailFound = true
}
```

If at the end of the loop, the flag is still false that means that the email was not found so you can safely show the suitable alert message.